# Configuring POJOMappingFeature without web.xml

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

I am using Jersey to marshall a Java object to JSON, as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.IOException;

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/test")
public Response replay(String input) throws IOException {
    return Response.ok().entity(new MyClass()).build();
}
```

Am receiving the following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.company.MyClass, and Java type class com.company.MyClass, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
```

I understand that the solution here is to :

1. Add the `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` dependency
2. Use `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature`

`POJOMappingFeature` is normally configured in `web.xml`.
Is there an alternative for applications which are annotation driven and do not use `web.xml`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add this to your pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency is normally commented out if you have created your project from the Jersey maven archetype.

com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature is only for version 1.* of Jersey. The package name changed from com.sun.* to org.glassfish.* from version 1 to 2 of Jersey.